# Plain-text formatting in python

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that makes new text files with python and I was wondering if it's possible to do some trivial text formatting when writing to a .txt file with python. For example, I'd like to underline some words and in some cases, use bold text.

Comment: If you're writing a text file, then I guess the best you could do is either use markup/markdown of some sort

Comment: Plain text files don't have that kind of formatting, by definition. What kind of formatting do you want? Markdown or something similar?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean. What i'm looking for is a way to underline a .txt file so when i open it up with notepad for example, i get the word underlined :D

Comment: And what you're being told is that you can't do that! (short of using some kind of markup/markdown or file format that supports it)

Comment: I got this, ok :d. but, even when i write to a file like this: <b>Hello world</b> and then i save it as .rtf and then open it with a wordpad, my text still doesn't get formatted, it just simply prints the <b>hello world</b>. Am i getting something wrong ?

Comment: Yes - you've effectively just written text containing HTML to an RTF file - RTF uses different syntax etc... to display formatted text...

Comment: Why do you think it's called **plain** text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.txt` files do not have formatting. You would have to use HTML or some other format of rich text/markup.

Example of HTML:

```html
This is <b>bold</b> text. This is <u>underlined</u>.
```

Comment: So it isn't possible to see the underlined or bold text in notepad, right?

Comment: @geekkid No, it is not, unless you use rtf or something of the sort. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format

Comment: As a note, you'll need wordpad (or whatever it's called these days) for RTF files

Comment: Yes, just plain notepad can't do anything like that. Wordpad is preinstalled on all Windows computers, I think.

Comment: should i just save my files as .rtf then , instead of .txt ? Are there any drawbacks doing this ?

Comment: @geekkid The downside is that you have to parse it, and that rtf is somewhat complicated.

Comment: @geekkid but for what you're doing, you could just use HTML and save it as `.html`. Then open it in a web browser.

Comment: Oh, thank you, that's working well! But on a sidenote, would it be unprofessional to save files as .html format instead of .txt for a client who just needs some printable files to be outputed (.txt seems a bit more 'clean' if you know what i mean :D)

Comment: @geekkid With txt, you can't format. So if you have to format, use HTML or RTF.

Comment: ok, i'll go with html then. Thank you !